# Small, unequal, sample size significance using MANOVA

Tags: manova

I am testing the hypothesis, **"there is no difference between 3 materials"**, with a small sample size. I have 3 materials and 2 DVs (test 1-2). They also have a different number of replications as seen below. Six material-1, two material-2, and two material-3. Unfortunately this is all of the data that I will get due to the difficulty of the tests.

```
Material    Test1    Test2
________    _____    _____

 'mat1'       5        3  
 'mat1'       4        7  
 'mat1'       8        7  
 'mat1'       8        2  
 'mat1'       2        2  
 'mat1'       5        5  
 'mat2'       5       10  
 'mat2'       7        4  
 'mat3'       8        6  
 'mat3'       8        3
```

I am using Matlab to run a MANOVA analysis using the repeated measures function with 95% confidence. The output from the analysis is shown below;

```
Within       Between      Statistic     Value        F       RSquare    df1    df2    pValue 
________    ___________    _________    _______    _______    _______    ___    ___    _______

Constant    (Intercept)    Pillai       0.11538    0.91304    0.11538     1      7     0.37113
Constant    (Intercept)    Wilks        0.88462    0.91304    0.11538     1      7     0.37113
Constant    (Intercept)    Hotelling    0.13043    0.91304    0.11538     1      7     0.37113
Constant    (Intercept)    Roy          0.13043    0.91304    0.11538     1      7     0.37113
Constant    Material       Pillai       0.20218    0.88696    0.20218     2      7     0.45359
Constant    Material       Wilks        0.79782    0.88696    0.20218     2      7     0.45359
Constant    Material       Hotelling    0.25342    0.88696    0.20218     2      7     0.45359
Constant    Material       Roy          0.25342    0.88696    0.20218     2      7     0.45359
```

It seems to clearly show that the null hypothesis holds true. I want to make sure that I went through the process correctly and I used the "best" method for the data I have. Should I do separate t-tests for the materials because of the small sample size? Is there some post-hoc analysis I should be doing? I am giving myself a crash course in statistics over the last few weeks, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean that there are 3 inndependant variables with an unequal number of repeated measures, or is this a single predictor ("material") with 3 levels, and an unequal number of independant observations?

Comment: @chl A single predictor with 3 levels. I updated the post.

Comment: Ok, I got close results using R or Stata with their respective `manova` function. You cannot reject the null in this case. However, the correlation between your two outcomes is zero; combined with the low sample size, it is diffcult to conclude.

Comment: @chl Understood. Thank you for your help.